# Stream PC screen to Raspberry Pi

Tags: streaming-video, ethernet, monitoring

I would like to stream my computer's screen content to my Raspberry Pi, so what I see on my computer screen, I see on my Raspberry Pi's monitor.

Is this possible? I know the Raspberry Pi has a 100 Mbit ethernet port, so what I need is some software to show what I see, stream this on my network and let Raspberry Pi show it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You must install a VNC server on your PC and have the client run on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative answer - to support higher resolutions - for streaming video alone (no remote control):
on desktop: use VLC to encode your screen with h264 and serve it over http (you should be able to do it with help of GUI)
on raspberry: use omxplayer, as it takes advantage of hardware decoder to play your h264 high resolution stream. If omxplayer won't support http out of the box use mkfifo, like this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/stream
wget -O /tmp/stream http://yourlinkToStream &> /dev/null &
omxplayer -r /tmp/stream
```

If you REALLY want to have this and keyboard/mouse input you could use software like synergy (http://synergy-foss.org/), but it will be much worse experience than e.g. VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Any remote control software will do what you are asking.  VNC, TeamViewer, LogMeIn, Gotomypc, the possibilities are endless, but keep in mind that these softwares are not designed for full blown graphics and smooth fades, etc.